# How to distinguish chatbots from humans?

Tags: chat, bot

I hate chatbots. How can I detect them in chatboxes? For instance, I went to [this website](https://www.odoo.com), and a chatbox appeared, offering help. The conversation is below:

[image]

The last answer is too generic. It clearly didn't engage with my request for proof. A human would have most likely reacted somehow to it.

Then, I went into the website using another computer, and again engaged in a talk (with the same "subject"), receiving no reply:

[image]

This doesn't prove anything, but it implies either an algorithm with no space for a digression or a human in a very restricted environment.

So, the question is, **how can I distinguish between a bot and a human in a chat?** Is there a specific type of questions that have been shown to unmask one from the other, with great certainty?

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you just talked to a human, not a chatbot in this particular case (scenario). The baseline for distinguishing between human and bot is in the complexity of a question. If the answer to your question can't be anyhow derivated from your question (or individual parts of your question), then your question is test-worthy to spot a bot.

Only first input from your conversation was non-human:

[image: 1]

But this can't be considered as an input of a chatbot, because this is just pre-programmed phrase which is shown every time the chat window is triggered.

Then, your 1st, 2nd and 3rd chat input are highly off-topic (btw. like this question) and even hostile to some degree. Just imagine yourself on the other side how would you respond. You can test it yourself with this example where every row will be separate chat entry you type in (in array or dialogue):

```
Hello,
i wana ask
what does your cmpany 
name standfor?, 
whats themeanaing?
```

Comment: Thanks. Why is the question off-topic? Musn't off-topic questions remain unanswered?

Comment: @luchonacho maybe they should... because its too broad and primarily opinion-based, eg. kinda philosophic